# How to implement multiple forms for one template

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm new to Django. I have multiple forms for different calculations (etc Form1, Form2, Form3, ...) on my blog page.
Each blog post (post/1) will have a button at the page with a link to open specific form template (post_form.html) for that post (e.g. post/1/form/) with a form in it. (Post1 - Form1, Post2 - Form 2, etc..)

Could someone help with the logic of implementation of this? How to better set up urls, models and forms?

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category , on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='Concrete')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User , on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='calc_pics')
    formId = models.IntegerField()

class L_section_prop_calc(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    tf = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=3)
    tw = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=3)
    height = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=3)
```

urls.py

```
path('post/<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
```

forms.py

```
class Calc_L_Section_Prop_Form(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = L_section_prop_calc
    fields = ['tw','tf','height']
```

I'm do not know if I need to create a model for each form. Is there a better way?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'm assuming, since your question is a little hard to read. You have `Post` objects, each of which has a related `Calc_L_Section_Prop_Form` object. You want to have a link from `/post/1/` to a page with a form for the related `Calc_L_Section_Prop_Form`.

If that is correct, then this is how I would go about doing that.

Add a field onto your `Calc_L_Section_Prop_Form` model to connect it to your post. If there will only be one calculation per blog post you can use a `OneToOneField`. The rest of your models are fine.

**models.py**

```py
...

class L_section_prop_calc(models.Model):
    post = models.OneToOneField(Post, models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

Create a view to handle the form for the calculations.

**views.py**

```py
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

...

class CalcUpdateView(generic.UpdateView):
    fields = ['tw','tf','height']
    model = L_section_prop_calc

    def get_object(self):
        return get_object_or_404(
            self.get_queryset(),
            post__pk=self.kwargs['pk'],
        )
```

Finally put in another `path` to use this view.

**urls.py**

```py
    ...
    path('post/<int:pk>/form/', CalcUpdateView.as_view(), name='calc-update'),
```

Comment: The problem is that L_sect_prop form/class is one of many calcs I want to do.  Lets call it Form 1. I will have as many different forms as number of posts. For each post there is a special form. Does that change your answer?

Comment: I was assuming a one-to-one direct relationship between the `L_section_prop_calc` models and `Post` models. Different calculations but stored in one model.

Comment: The problem is that every calc requires different input fields = different variables. I have no idea how to store it as it cannot be in one model. How to assign to each post a different form?

Comment: That is whole lot more complicated. You might wind up needing to create your own form factories (see Django's here: https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.2.4/django/forms/models.py#L473).